# Grouped products are displaying more than once with different product name with same values in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am really struggling for this. please help me.

I created grouped product using this link's code :http://pastebin.com/8Ffx2ztp

If i create  1 grouped associated product , following is displaying in frontend

Product name           CUTTER                 DIAMETER          CUTTING          LENGTH
3.2M4                  3.2mm               8mm           5/16"            3m

If i create 2 grouped associated products, following is displaying in frontend[no change in code]

Product name          CUTTER             DIAMETER          CUTTING          LENGTH
3.2M4                 3.2mm            8mm                  5/16"         3m

4.2M4                 3.2mm             8mm                  5/16              3m

If i create 3 grouped associated products- 3 rows [with product name changed], 
If i create 4 grouped associated products - 4 rows so on....

How to change values of second product[row]..?... please tell me , where i have to change the code
to give different values for second row..?... please edit the code and post here. 
 or send to me at realworker99atgmaildotcom

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As group product can be simply created from adminpannel. Most of things in magento can be done without programming, just refer the below link for better understanding

"http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide"